# JQGrid Drop Down Menu/Text Field in one

Tags: jqgrid

I have a requirement to load a set of pre-defined values from the database but also give a user ability to enter a custom values as well. Good example is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/

```
<label>Choose a browser from this list:
<input list="browsers" name="myBrowser" /></label>
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
  <option value="Microsoft Edge">
</datalist>
```

Is it possible to implement this feature in JQGrid?

Comment: Hello, There is no problem to add this as custom element, but my question is: what will happen if new item is used form the user - should this item be updated or you want to refresh the list after the insert is done or do not want udate. More detais on this will help.

Answer (score 0):

This will only happen in the edit mode one per row. It should function exactly as as selecting from a drop down, only one value will be displayed and updated/saved. I will have to use is for only one column where each row will have a list of dynamic predefined values coming from the database.

Here is my start:

```
<datalist id="browsers">
<option value="Chrome">
<option value="Firefox">
<option value="Internet Explorer">
<option value="Opera">
<option value="Safari">
<option value="Microsoft Edge">
</datalist>  

function myelem (value, options) {
var el = document.createElement("input");
el.type='text';
options.id = 'myBrowser';
el.setAttribute("list", "browsers");
return el;
```

}

The question is how to populate the datalist dynamically for each row based on the next column value and after exiting the edit mode save the selected value to the db?
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

If a value was previously saved for this column it should be displayed. When a user enters an edit mode the previously displayed value will be at the top (default) but the same set of predefined values should be available in the drop down with the option to enter a new custom value.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found this very interesting and have created new article in our [Guriddo Knowledge base](http://guriddo.net/?kbe_knowledgebase=using-datalist-drop-down-menu-in-form-edit) where I explain in detail how to do this